# AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'setdefault'|| self.__connection_settings.setdefault("charset", "utf8")

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I am getting below error. Unable to find it. please help me to find it. Thanks in advance.

File "/home/ec2-user/my_app/env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymysqlreplication/binlogstream.py", line 178, in **init**
    self.__connection_settings.setdefault("charset", "utf8")
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

```
import json
import boto3
import pymysql
import socket,array
import pandas as pd
from pymysqlreplication import BinLogStreamReader
from pymysqlreplication.row_event import (
   DeleteRowsEvent,
   UpdateRowsEvent,
   WriteRowsEvent,
)
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',password='root')

def main():
  kinesis = boto3.client("kinesis",region_name='ap-south-1')
  stream = BinLogStreamReader(
            connection_settings=connection,
            only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent],
            only_schemas=["test"],
            log_file='mysql-bin.000003',
            log_pos=2566,
           server_id=100)
  for binlogevent in stream:
    for row in binlogevent.rows:
       event = {"schema": binlogevent.schema,
       "table": binlogevent.table,
       "type": type(binlogevent).__name__,
       "row": row
       }       
      kinesis.put_record(StreamName="<TestStream>", Data=json.dumps(event), PartitionKey="default",)
      print (json.dumps(event))
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`connection` should be a dictionary. For example:

```
 connection = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "root",
    "passwd": "root"
}
```

An example of a correct usage of `BinLogStreamReader` is [here](https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication/blob/master/examples/dump_events.py)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin. That's helped me

Comment: @KUMARSOURAV No problem. If so, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.